# Is there an option to trim the remaining whitespace to the right?

Tags: margins, preview, crop

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
$
\frac{1}{3}=0.333\ldots \Rightarrow 1=3\times\frac{1}{3}=3\times 0.333\ldots=0.999\ldots
$\\
Thus $1=0.999\ldots$.
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an option to trim the remaining whitespace to the right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extra whitespace you see is because a paragraph with the width `\linewidth` is created here. You can use the `{varwidth}{<max width>}` environment from the `varwidth` package to reduce the paragraph width to its minimum. This uses a `minipage` environment internally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$
\frac{1}{3}=0.333\ldots \Rightarrow 1=3\times\frac{1}{3}=3\times 0.333\ldots=0.999\ldots
$\\
Thus $1=0.999\ldots$.
\end{varwidth}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

---

You can also use the `standalone` class with the `preview` and `varwidth=<max width|default: \linewidth>` options which will use more or less the exact same code internally:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$
\frac{1}{3}=0.333\ldots \Rightarrow 1=3\times\frac{1}{3}=3\times 0.333\ldots=0.9
99\ldots
$\\
Thus $1=0.999\ldots$.
\end{document}
```

Also the default option `crop` works here instead of `preview` but does not use the `preview` package internally.

Comment: Why do you provide `preview` option if `crop` works? In other words, is there a case in which you need to load `preview` package in `standalone.cls` implementation?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: In the first version of `standalone` (v0.x) I used the `preview` package to crop the content. However, this showed some issues (e.g. with XeLaTeX and PDF patterns) and limitations, so I started to write my own cropping code which I called `crop`. I made it the default with v1.x, but I still provide the original `preview` option which used to be the default. If used it loads the `preview` package.

Comment: Without considering the issues you mentioned above, is `crop` better than `preview`? For example, is `crop` more accurate than `preview`, etc, etc?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: No, its not more accurate. Both simply use the official dimensions of the content. However, `crop` does use *restricted horizontal mode* (like in `\mbox`) to store the content, which avoids the issue of getting a paragraph when having a trailing empty line after a small picture environment, but doesn't work with content which depends on vertical mode, like display-math. For this you need to use `varwidth` around the content first. AFAIK `preview` works using the output routine, which might clash with other code which modifies this. `crop` simply resizes the page.